# Distributing self-signed SSL certificates: How to skip requirement to import to key store

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

I have developed a Java application that uses a self-signed SSL certificate to communicate with my server through https.

Now I would like to share the application with some of my clients. Is there any way for them to skip importing the certificate to their keystore? Or do they always have to import it manually?

Comment: Are you talking about one-way SSL where your clients need to know your self-signed server certificate? Or are you talking about two-way SSL where your clients need to present a (self-signed) certificate to the server? And where do your clients import their certificate until now?

Comment: My clients have to import the certificate in the way that is described here: http://my.opera.com/karmazilla/blog/how-to-grab-the-certificate-from-a-website-and-import-it-with-java-keytool. That is to complex, so arenthere any ways to simplify the procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the link that you posted you are talking about one-way SSL and you need to let your clients know the server's self-signed certificate (right?).
So what your client application needs is a so-called **trust store**. A trust store is a java keystore holding all certificates that you trust, e.g. the certificate of the server you want to connect. The `cacerts` file in your java installation contains various certificates that are trusted by default.

Instead of installing the server certificate into the `cacerts` file of the clients' Java installation, you can provide your own truststore containing the server certificate together with your client application. The client applications need then to be started with the system property `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/your/truststore`.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. Each client should use his own SSL certificate: generate a keypair locally, generate a certificate, and send it to you offline. Using a single certificate for all clients is basically equivalent to not using one at all: you can't uniquely identify the client so it's all pointless.

Comment: Can you please specify more details. The server software is third party and it came with a SSL preinstalled, so I cannot manage it. For each client, I import the certificate in the way it says here: http://my.opera.com/karmazilla/blog/how-to-grab-the-certificate-from-a-website-and-import-it-with-java-keytool. Is it possible to do that automatically in some way?

Comment: Can you please specify your requirement first, as requested by @Stefan Ferstl? Are you talking about client authentication, which requires generation of a client key-pair and certificate, or about installing a *server* certificate into each client's *truststore?*